# What types of iPhone UIControl is this?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, uicontrol

I'm not sure if these are custom made buttons or if they are standard, but what controls are the "Core stats" and ""Sensor Stats" toggle buttons?

http://cultofmac.cultofmaccom.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/mapmyfitness-31.jpg

I've made custom made Radio Buttons, but I can't find where these common controls come from

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called a [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).

Answer (score 1):

Those would be UISegmentedControls. Here's a link to the documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807